# Android RecyclerView item sequence issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, listadapter

I am new to Android. I am currently trying to build an app having a list view screen where a list of books is displayed. On each item, there is an image downloaded from URL and 2 icons who's image resource is set based on values set in a POJO object.

My Adapter code is as below:

```
    Context context = view.getContext();
    view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    view.setAdapter(new MySearchBooksItemRecyclerViewAdapter(SearchBooks.ITEMS, mListener, getActivity()));
```

---

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: binding variables of object: " + position);
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: holder value: " + holder.mItem);
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: holder value: " + holder.mTitle);
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: holder value: " + holder.mISBN);

    holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
    holder.mTitle.setText(mValues.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.mTitle.setTag(mValues.get(position).getId());
    holder.mISBN.setText(mValues.get(position).getIsbn());
    holder.mDesc.setText(mValues.get(position).getDesc());
    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new ClickListItem());

    getImages(holder.mBookImage, mValues.get(position).getImage());

    if (bookList.get(mValues.get(position).getId()) != null) {
        holder.mIsFav.setImageResource(bookList.get(mValues.get(position).getId()).isBookmarked() ? R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp : R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_white_24dp);
        holder.mIsDownloaded.setImageResource(new File(bookList.get(mValues.get(position).getId()).getSavedBookName()).exists() ? R.drawable.ic_offline_pin_white_24dp : R.drawable.ic_get_app_white_24dp);
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: variables bound: " + mValues.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount: item count: " + mValues.size());
    return mValues.size();
}
```

---

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@color/background_material_dark"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bookImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="100dp"

            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_img_tu" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/is_fav_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_white_24dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/is_downloaded_image"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/background_material_dark"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_get_app_white_24dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now the problem comes when I scroll through the screen. in the first load the icon values and images are perfectly loaded. but when I scroll across and return back, the 'onBindViewHolder' is again called and wrong random values are used. thus showing wrong icons in the images.

can anyone help me how to fix this...??

i don't want the images to be reloaded or the icons to be refreshed unless needed

Comment: add else statement where you checking the id for null, in else clause populate static images, hope this will help.

Comment: i am skeptical as to how that would help...i am gonna try it...if it helps then ill let you know...till then any other insight would also be helpful

Comment: Wow...Amazingly somehow that worked...i would like to understand why it was happening though...could you please submit an answer with some details as to why was it an issue before

Comment: yes sure I am adding answer that helps you to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add else statement where you checking the id for null, in else clause populate static images or any place holders.

This happens when you did not load image in ImageView and ImageView get the random image. 
In your case you have only if statement so ImageView does not load any image when if statement has false. Recyclerview recycles the view but we have to make sure to populate all the values in recyclerview row otherwise previous images/data will be appear.

Hope this helps. If it solve your problem then accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is don't iterate through your list using the **position** passed by the `onBindViewHolder`.

Instead call `getItemViewType(position)` and use this to iterate through your list, after you return the position associated with each view holder:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

The truth is your view holder is not saved in a sequential order and unrelated with the ordering provided by the `onBindViewHolder`. By calling the `getItemViewHolder` you're essentially associating the positions to each view holder.